# pine-script, what log(pi * (atr(factor)) meaning

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I'm trying to understand this code before rewrite with Julia.

```
//
// @author LazyBear
// @credits http://freethinkscript.blogspot.com/2009/05/only-scalpers-channel-that-you-will.html
//
study(title = "Scalper's Channel [LazyBear]", shorttitle="weak_volume_dependency [LB]", overlay=true)
length = input(20)
factor = input(15)
src = input(close)
pi = atan(1)*4
Average(x,y) => (sum(x,y) / y)
scalper = Average(src, factor) - log(pi * (atr(factor)))
scalper_line= plot(scalper, color=blue, linewidth=1)
hi = plot (highest(length), color=fuchsia)
lo = plot (lowest(length), color=fuchsia)
```

But don't understand what this line doing `scalper = Average(src, factor) - log(pi * (atr(factor)))`